# IntegrityError while trying to update many-to-many relationship with SQLAlchemy and Postgresql

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have the following tabes:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Table  
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, declarative_base, Session  
  
import consts  
  
engine = create_engine(consts.POSTGRES_DATABASE_URI)  
Base = declarative_base()  
  
cities_to_buses = Table('cities_to_buses', Base.metadata,  
                     Column('city_id', Integer, ForeignKey('cities.city_id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True),  
                     Column('bus_id', Integer, ForeignKey('buses.bus_id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True))  
  
  
class City(Base):  
    __tablename__ = 'cities'  
  
    city_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)  
    city_name = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)  
  
    buses = relationship('Bus', secondary='cities_to_buses', back_populates='cities', cascade='all, delete')  
  
  
class Bus(Base):  
    __tablename__ = 'buses'  
  
    bus_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)  
    bus_company = Column(String, index=True)  
    bus_number = Column(String, index=True)  
  
    cities = relationship('City', secondary='cities_to_buses', back_populates='buses', cascade='all, delete')
```

- Each city can have multiple buses
- Cities can have the same exact bus (same `bus_company` and `bus_number`)

The function below gets `city_dict`, which contains the `city_name` and a list of `buses`.
The goal of that function is to update the `buses` of the `city` so that:

1. If there is a relationship already between the same `city` and `bus`- keep it.
2. If there is a relationship *but* the `bus` isn't in the new list of `buses` - remove it.
3. If there isn't a relationship and the `bus` is in the new list of `buses` - add it.

```
def add_city_buses_to_db(city_dict: dict):  
    with Session(engine, autoflush=False) as session:  
        existing_city_query = session.query(City).filter_by(city_name=city_dict['city_name'])  
        if city := existing_city_query.first():  
            existing_city_query.update(city_dict['columns'])  
            city.buses = []  
        else:  
            city = City(city_name=city_dict['city_name'], **city_dict['columns'])  
  
        for bus in city_dict['buses']:  
            if existing_bus := session.query(Bus).filter_by(bus_company=bus['bus_company'],  
                                                            bus_number=bus['bus_number']).first():  
                city.buses.append(existing_bus)  
            else:  
                city.buses.append(Bus(**bus))  
  
        session.add(city)  
        session.commit()
```

The problem occurs with case (1.) - when I append `existing_bus` and then run `session.commit()`, I am getting the following error :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "cities_to_buses_pkey" DETAIL: Key (city_id, bus_id)=(33480, 458019) already exists.
```

Looking at the queries I do see that sqlalchemy tries to insert again the same row, but shouldn't it understand this is the same object because I am appending the `existing_bus`?

I can do the workaround of removing the `primary_key` constraint, but then I'll have duplicate lines.

Another option which I am not sure about is to remove all the relationships and then insert them, but I do think I am just missing something very basic and fixable in the current way.

UPDATE: putting `session.flush()` under `city.buses = []` seems to solve it (?) *only when* there is an `existing_bus` and we aren't creating a new `Bus` object, the error changes to:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint busess_pkey DETAIL:  Key (bus_id)=(9) already exists.
```